# If $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_1^{i}p_2^{-a_i}$ converges and is rational does that imply that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_2^{-a_i}$ is also rational

Tags: sequences-and-series, rationality-testing

For primes $p_1$ and $p_2$ and a monotonically increasing sequence of natural numbers $a_i$, if $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_1^{i}p_2^{-a_i}$ converges and is rational does that imply that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_2^{-a_i}$ is also rational?

The converse is easy to show (assuming convergence), but I can't seem to make it work in the forward direction. It's also interesting whether there are certain choices of $p_1$ and $p_2$ that make the problem easier or harder, since for example $p_2 = 2$ means that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_2^{a_i}$ is an arbitrary real between 0 and 1.

Comment: What's the argument for the converse?

Comment: Just realized I said it backwards. Corrected it with an edit. The easy direction follows because if $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_2^{-a_i}$ is rational, then there exists some number, which we can write in base $p_2$ as $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_2^{-i}b_i$ such that the product $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_2^{-a_i} \sum_{i=0}^\infty p_2^{-i}b_i$ has only finitely many digits. It follows that it has only finitely many terms. If you do the multiplication, the terms are the same as those of the product $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_1^i p_2^{-a_i} \sum_{i=0}^\infty p_1^i p_2^{-i}b_i$, up to a factor of $p_1^i$.

Comment: What you have in the body is the inverse of what you have in the title. Please edit so they say the same thing.

Comment: Whoops, thanks Gerry! Fixed.

Comment: Your comment above is flawed, clarify "some number" and $b_i$ and the two multiplications you'll see where the problem is.

Comment: @reuns, I'm guessing a little at what you're driving at, but "some number" here doesn't necessarily mean the denominator of the rational described by $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_2^{-a_i}$. In fact it can't, since all of these numbers are between 0 and 1. But it can represent that denominator divided by $p_2^k$ for some $k$, and that will still give a finite sum. Each $b_i$ is an integer between 0 and $p_2$. The multiplications are $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^j p_2^{-a_k + k - j}b_{k-j}$ and $\sum_{j=0}^\infty p_1^j \sum_{k=0}^j p_2^{-a_k + k - j} b_{k-j}$. I hope that clarifies.